# Storing flask-jwt auth token. Can I / should I store in database?

Tags: python, ajax, flask, jwt

I don't know if any of this is the correct way to do this. But here it goes.

(Please let me know if any of this is totally wrong)

I want to store a JWT against a user in flask, is it correct for me to store this in the database?

Currently I'm attempting to check on each request if they have a valid token but am getting a new token each time.

I'm using this.

```
app.before_request(check_token)

def check_token(*args, **kwargs):
    if current_user:
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            if not hasattr(current_user, "token"):
                set_token()
            elif current_user.token_time + timedelta(seconds=current_app.config["TOKEN_SECONDS"]) < datetime.utcnow():
                set_token()
```

Obviously I've found it doesn't preserve the current_user so the token changes every time I make a new request.

1) Is it good practise to save this token in the database? I'm giving it 300 seconds currently. Or is there another way to save it against the current user?

2) I'm using Flask to render the page and I store the users token like this

```
<button data-token="asdkjhakjsdnkcz8323lkn42lk3n4kj2nkjn2kj3b4kjnlkj32">
```

Which I then pass to javascript Xhttp requests to update post comments on the fly. Seems like I probably shouldn't but with such a short validity period seems ok?

Comment: The main advantage of a JWT is that it is independent of the system structure and persistence. It you want throw that advantage away you can store and check it. But why are using a JWT then?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point of it? But I use create_access_token output to authenticate api requests that have @jwt_required decorator. These tokens appear to have to be passed with the header of the request. I need a way to remember them? And unless I'm going completely mad, I can't see how.

Comment: The point is that you don't have to remember them. Everything needed is inside the signed token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision whether to store the JWT token depends ultimately on the required security strategy.

The JWT token as well as the refresh tokens indeed store in themselves the sign time and their expiration, but this is not relevant on whether to use a persistent storage regarding their sessions.

From the [Flask-JWT documentation](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/blocklist_and_token_revoking/):

> In production, you will want to use some form of persistent storage (database, redis, etc) to store your JWTs. It would be bad if your application forgot that a JWT was revoked if it was restarted. We can provide some general recommendations on what type of storage engine to use, but ultimately the choice will depend on your specific application and tech stack.

Having said that, if the nature of your information is not so sensitive that a possible leak of the tokens matters, then you can avoid the hassle of persistent storage altogether. Otherwise, on logout you would want to revoke the token by closing the stored session.

Comment: 2 years too late, but thank you none the less :)